# javascript changing location hash of a window, also adds the fragments to the document title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, back-button

I'm using [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), which is a great jquery plugin by Ben Alman, and as the name implies provides browser history behavior for a javascript dynamic pages.

My problem is that the fragments are getting stacked in the browser's title, when in debug I can see it in the document object (`document.nameProp, document.title`).

Is that a know issue when handling the hash part of a URL? if so is there a fix for it or should i maintain it manually?

Comment: Rule of thumb: When you use a framework, don't blame Javascript (as in "javascript changing location hash...")